# Whats wrong with this code to add a class to the header?

Tags: javascript, html

could sb help me with this code? Cant find why it isnt working...

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 10,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if(distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header, "is-not-top");
            classie.remove(header, "is-top");
        } else {
            if(classie.has(header, "is-not-top")) {
                classie.remove(header, "is-not-top");
                classie.add(header, "is-top");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

This should add the class is-not-top to the header classes, but it doesnt do this... Whats wrong? thx :D

EDIT:
changed the code to:

```
        function init() {
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        shrinkOn = 10,
        header = document.getElementById("header");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
        header.classList.add("is-not-top");
        header.classList.remove("is-top");
    } else {
        if (header.classList.has("is-not-top")) {
            header.classList.remove("is-not-top");
            header.classList.add("is-top");
        }
    }
});
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `window.onload = init();` does not mean what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, when setting a callback, refer to it by `name`, not `name()`, like `window.onload = init`.

```
header = document.querySelector("header");
```

Two things: First, `querySelector` selects one element. `querySelectorAll` selects all matching elements, like JQuery. Second, `word` on its own searches for `<word>` elements. If you want to find `<div class="word">` elements, query for `.word`.

So, the new line looks like this.

```
header = document.querySelectorAll(".header");
```

I am presuming that `classie` can operate on NodeLists, since I haven't used it before.

Comment: now i changed the code like you see, and it adds the class is-not-top, but it doesnt remove it again...